# Command line "find" piped to sed on Windows not working

Tags: windows, sed, command-line

I'm building a website that uses the Angular Material design package. Recently after an update, the package changed the names of many CSS styling classes, thus breaking old code. The package provided a command that can be run to replace all instances of the old name in `.css` and `.scss` files with the new name ([source](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/2790#issue-202984769)):

```
find . -type f -name "*.scss" -o -name "*.css"| xargs sed -i 's/\.md-/\.mat-/g'
```

I think this is meant to replace all `.md-` with `.mat-` in the styling files found in the project directory and sub-directories. After making sure that I can run both `find` and `xargs` on my Windows machine, I tried to run the command. Here is what I get:

```
C:\project>find . -type f -name "*.scss" -o -name "*.css"| xargs sed -i 's/\.md-/\.mat-/g'
File not found - "*.css"
sed: no input files

C:\project>find . -type f -name "*.scss"| xargs sed -i 's/\.md-/\.mat-/g'
Access denied - .
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
sed: no input files
```

IRunning as Aministrator makes no difference. I have no idea where to go from here. What's the matter? Is there a different way to do this on Windows 7?

Comment: Windows `find` is a vastly different app/command than *nix `find`.

Comment: Typing `find /?` at a command prompt would reveal that Windows find does not accept any of those parameters, which would be a strong indication that you're not running a Windows version of the file. Contact whoever gave you the *command* and ask them for the proper version for your OS.

Comment: @zwer thanks! that led me to the right answer. I'll write it up if no one else does.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have a proper `xargs` and `sed` on your Windows system, you can try using `dir` instead of `find`, something like:

```
dir /b /s *.*css | xargs sed -i 's/\.md-/\.mat-/g'
```

Comment: I also have some `.scss` files to process

Comment: @BeetleJuice - this should pick both `.css` and `.scss` files, but if you want to specify them explicitly: `dir /b /s *.css /s *.scss | xargs sed -i 's/\.md-/\.mat-/g'`

Comment: I solved it about 2 minutes after reading your comment by using the right `find` program (the linux equivalent could be found in `/path/to/git/usr/bin` so I didn't get to try your method (if I test it I'll be back to select your answer).  +1 for the help though; you let me to my solution.